# Compute array product on an array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

In order to compute the cartesian product in Ruby, one can use `Array#product`, how is the syntax if I have an array of arrays and want to compute the product?

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] => [[1,3,5], [2,3,5], ...]
```

I am not sure, because in the Ruby documentation the `product` method is defined with an arbitrary number of arguments, so simply passing my arrays of arrays as an argument, like that:

`[].product(as) => [`

does not suffice. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method takes multiple arguments, but not an array containing arguments. So you have to use it in this way:

```
[1,2].product [3,4], [5,6]
```

If `as` is your array of arrays, you will have to "splat" it like this:

```
as[0].product(*as[1..-1])
```

Comment: `[].product(*as)` always produces an empty array, which is a shame, as it would be nice to do what the OP was asking without having to draw out one of the arrays as the first object.

Comment: There's a discussion related to this [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6499), where some people argued for class methods like `Array.product(*arrays)`. I think this would have been useful, but I guess it didn't happen.

Comment: ```(as[0]).product(*as.drop(1))``` is a version that works

Comment: Mateusz Konieczny, thank you for the improvement! I only varied the style a little.

Comment: @reducingactivity: ...and if `as` can be mutated, one could write `as.shift.product(*as)`.

Answer (score 2):

Closest notation I've got is:

```ruby
:product.to_proc.call(*as)

# shorthand
:product.to_proc.(*as)
:product.to_proc[*as]
```